# why is ThreadProcessing type used in this snippet?

Tags: java-me

```
class Process implements Runnable{
  private ThreadProcessing MIDlet;

  public Process(ThreadProcessing MIDlet){ 
    this.MIDlet = MIDlet;
    System.out.println("Thread Process...");
  }
```

What is the purpose of using this(ThreadProcessing) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThreadProcessing is the name of the class that extends MIDlet.

...
public class ThreadProcessing extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{
  private Display display;
...

It's higher up in the code.